# iOS convert bool value to string

Tags: ios

I have a bool value associated with a call I want to pass out of my iOS program as a string. I have tried the following:

```
  NSString *connectedString = [self.selectedBeacon.isConnected stringValue];
```

But I'm not getting anything out.

Can someone please correct me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `isConnected` is a `BOOL` type it shouldn't even compile. If it's `NSNumber` you should get "1" or "0".

Do you want "YES" to "NO" string? Solution:

A) If a BOOL type:

```
NSString *connectedString = self.selectedBeacon.isConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO";
```

B) If `NSNumber` add a category method to this class like:

```
- (NSString *)boolValueString {
    // if this contains BOOL value
    return [self boolValue] ? @"YES" : @"NO";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting Bool To String **Swift 3** / **Swift 4**

```
let boolValue = true
print (String(boolValue))
```

**Log**

```
true
```